# How to apply the same rules to several locations with Nginx?

Tags: nginx

In a project I have very large nginx configuration with a lot of redundant lines.

The current state is like the following

```
location ~ /loc1/ {
    common rules;
}
location ~ /some/other/location/ {
    common rules;
}
location ~ /yet/anotherone {
    common rules;
}

etc .....
```

**What I'd like to have is seperated way where there is a generic rule template and a list of locations.**

In other related questions people have used regex to match several locations like so

```
location ~ (/loc1/|/some/other/location/|/yet/anotherone) {
    common rules;
}
```

In my case this would result in a huge line which would be very ugly to maintain.

Is there another cleaner way to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you really need them to be regular expressions?

Comment: probably not. is there a way to accomplish my goal using only exact matches?

Comment: You should learn the difference between prefix and regexp locations. See http://nginx.org/r/location

Comment: You're probably right but as far as I understand your comment doesn't adress the question I was asking at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First option is to put `common rules;` into file and `include` that file.

Another one is depend on what's exactly in that rules. In many cases you could move them to upper level like:

```
common rules;

location /a {
}

location /b/whatever {
}
```

and they will be inherited.